# Add a row to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a function, in order to create an array.

I'm able to create this array :

```
        $result = [ 'data' =>
        [0 =>
            [
                'months' => $months[0],
                'years' => $years[0],
                'date' => $date[0],
                'hr' => $hr[0],
                'isms' => $isms[0],
                'product' => $product[0],
                'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ],

        ],
    ];
```

And my prob is that i would like to create a function(PHP) in order to add some rows in this array. I would like to have this kind of result :

```
        $result = [ 'data' =>
        [0 =>
            [
                'months' => $months[0],
                'years' => $years[0],
                'date' => $date[0],
                'hr' => $hr[0],
                'isms' => $isms[0],
                'product' => $product[0],
                'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ],
            [
                'months' => $months[0],
                'years' => $years[0],
                'date' => $date[0],
                'hr' => $hr[0],
                'isms' => $isms[0],
                'product' => $product[0],
                'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

But everytime i try to push, it creates a "1=>...."

What can I do ? Could you help me ?

Comment: post your tried code

Comment: You are missing a level. The beginning should read as `$result = [ data' =>  [0 => [0 =>...` for it to make sense.

Comment: Also, this has very little to do with json and all to do with arrays

Comment: What you shown as expected output will also have 0,1,... indexes:- https://eval.in/990307  .... So what you want actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like below:-

```
 $result['data'][] = [
                'months' => $months[0],
                'years' => $years[0],
                'date' => $date[0],
                'hr' => $hr[0],
                'isms' => $isms[0],
                'product' => $product[0],
                'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/990308

Answer (score 0):

Your first array should be like this -

```
$result = [ 'data' =>
          [0 => 
              [0 =>
            [
                'months' => $months[0],
                'years' => $years[0],
                'date' => $date[0],
                'hr' => $hr[0],
                'isms' => $isms[0],
                'product' => $product[0],
                'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ],
             ],
          ],
      ];
```

Now use below code to add new row to your array -

```
$row = [
        'months' => $months[0],
        'years' => $years[0],
        'date' => $date[0],
        'hr' => $hr[0],
        'isms' => $isms[0],
        'product' => $product[0],
        'exploitation' => $exploitation[0]
            ];
$result['data'][0][] = $row;
print_r($result);
```